# Set multiple domains in one wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have wordpress in this domain:

```
http://www.Dummy.com/en
```

And want to use second domain such this:

```
 http://www.Dummy2.com
```

for this wordpress.

**How can I redirect Dummy2 to Dummy?**

This is some codes that I find out but I couldn't understand them:

## wp-config.php

```
define('WP_SITEURL', ((is_ssl() == true) ? 'https://' : 'http://').$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', ((is_ssl() == true) ? 'https://' : 'http://').$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Comment: So you have wordpress directory installed only in `http://www.Dummy.com/en`, and when users visit `http://www.Dummy2.com` you want to them automatically redirected to `http://www.Dummy.com/en`?

Comment: Yes exactly! @HastaDhana

Comment: It is possible to help me? @HastaDhana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to setup a redirect on a web server side rather than trying to make your website to do so when WordPress doesn't support multiple domains out-of-the-box. Depending on your chosen web server setup there are two answers for you.

**1. Apache**

You can use the **RedirectPermanent** directive with a simple VirtualHost, read more [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent)

```
#Location:/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.Dummy2.com
        RedirectPermanent / http://www.Dummy.com/en
</VirtualHost>
```

If only your `Dummy2` website would be configured as a WordPress-based site too then,a ternatively, you can add a redirect rule to `.htaccess` inside of your DocumentRoot configured for **www.Dummy2.com** site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.Dummy.com/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**2. IIS**

Make sure that you have an URL Rewrite module installed and simply create a new rewrite rule as follows:

```
<rule name="Dummy2.com" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url=".*" />
     <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*)?Dummy2.com" />                 
     </conditions>
     <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.Dummy.com/en/{R:0}" />
 </rule>
```

Comment: Thanks. Where is the file that must add `RedirectPermanent` to it? Is it enough  If I write `RedirectPermanent / http://www.Dummy.com/en` to `RedirectPermanent`  or need to write `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.Dummy.com/en/$1 [R=301,L]` next to it?  @kate-orlova

Comment: @mostafarahnama, you have to add the `RedirectPermanent` setting to your virtual host configuration, it is typically placed within the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file and/or in unique `.conf` files within the `/etc/httpd/conf.d` directory. Syntax of redirect is `RedirectPermanent URL-path URL`, so that you don't need the rewrite rule condition. If only your Dummy2 website would be configured as a WordPress-based site too then you could add that rewrite rule to its `.htaccess` file, but it is not your case.

Comment: I did way 1 `RedirectPermanent`. I also did set the DNS of my Domain. But I got this error in browser: `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN `. What is this? Is it because I recently set DNS and should I wait for one or two days?@kate-orlova

Comment: Try to point dummy2.com to the right IP address via your local `hosts` file and see what happens, it is located in `{YOUR_Windows}\System32\drivers\etc` folder.

Comment: I did that. I set my server ip for `dummy2.com` but the `dummy2.com` redirect to the other website that is in my server(`dummy0.com`). I saw something in `httpd.conf` about that `dummy0.com`. What is going on? @kate-orlova

Comment: My guess is: your solution is correct and works fine, though with the problem of being redirection `dummy2.com` to the default Server domain (instead of 
 redirection to `dummy.com/en`). Is my guess right? Does it really exist something like default domain in sever? @kate-orlova

Comment: You can redirect to any domain name even to _stackoverflow.com_, just try to amend your `RedirectPermanent` to go to any other domain instead of _dummy.com_. It will prove that the redirect approach works. Then you can review your DNS settings again - your domain DNS records and local `hosts` file. It would also be helpful to flush your local DNS cache by typing in `ipconfig /flushdns` in command line (`cmd`) and hitting Enter. Once your local DNS cache gets flushed you will see a _“Successfully flushed the DNS resolver Cache”_ message.

Comment: I've tested all these. But I'm still going to the `dummy0.com` domain. I accept your answer because of your hard work, but my problem is still exist.@kate-orlova

Comment: @mostafarahnama, I am glad that the redirect itself works for you. Please review other sites configuration in your `httpd.conf`, you can even remove them temporary and keep only Dummy and Dummy2 while testing. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: I edited your question. Also, if it is possible rep me. Also, if it is possible  for more study in web services and Apache ,introduce me to a books or articles  . Thanks @kate-orlova

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice, but:

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
switch ($host) {
  case 'www.Dummy.com/en':
    define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.Dummy.com/en/'); 
  break;
  case 'www.Dummy2.com':
    define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.Dummy2.com/');
  break;
  default:
    define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.Dummy2.com/');
  break;
}

define('WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'It isn't a good practice'?And in `default` variable why you define `dummy2.com`? Is it pissible to define `dummy.com/en`? And is it any other way-that been better than this way-  to impelement multiple domains in wordpress?  @sky

Comment: WordPress by default is not created to support multiple domains i think. And yes, is possible to define ```dummy.com/en``` by defualt. I do not know there is another way to set multiple domains.