# Subdomainare doing a 301 redirect without my knowledge

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm having a super weird issue for my site at baby-golightly.com. I route all traffic over Cloudflare and everything works fine for the main domain. However I've made a subdomain called blog.baby-golightly.com which somehow redirect all requests to the mainsite:

[image]

What I dont understand is how WP can make a redirect when its not even installed on the subdomain? I've looked into .htaccess but couldn't see any obvious error.

Comment: Check for ```WP_HOME``` & ```WP_SITEURL```. You can try to overwrite them - [https://stackoverflow.com/a/56310629/2245806](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56310629/2245806)

Comment: But that would be in the .htaccess no? As mentioned theres NO Wordpress installation on the subdomain only a single index.html file I've added there to see if I can connect. In the .htaccess of the main site at https://baby-golightly.com theres not anyone if these set.